# godot server flying bug

Tags: server, godot, gdscript

ok so i am new to godot and i am trying to make a multiplayer game but when i run it and start the server i am just flying very fast up here is the world code:

```
extends Node
var gravity = 19
@onready var main_menu = $CanvasLayer/mainmenu
@onready var address_entry = $CanvasLayer/mainmenu/MarginContainer/VBoxContainer/AdressEntry


const Player = preload("res://player.tscn")

const  PORT = 9999

var enet_peer = ENetMultiplayerPeer.new()

var cap = 1



func _unhandled_input(event):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("exit"):
        if cap == 0:
            Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
            cap = 1
        else:
            Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE
            cap = 0
            



func _on_hostbutton_pressed():
    main_menu.hide()
    Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
    enet_peer.create_server(PORT)
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = enet_peer
    
    add_player(multiplayer.get_unique_id())
    


func _on_joinbutton_pressed():
    pass # Replace with function body.

func add_player(peer_id):
    var player = Player.instantiate()
    player.name = str(peer_id)
    add_child(player)
```

and here is player code:

```
extends CharacterBody3D
@onready var camera = $Camera3D
@onready var anim_player = $AnimationPlayer
@onready var muzzle_flash = $Camera3D/Pistol/muzzelflash
var mouse_sens = 0.003

const SPEED = 7
const JUMP_VELOCITY = 10

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = 19

func _ready():
    Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_VISIBLE
    
func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        rotate_y(-event.relative.x * mouse_sens)
        camera.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * mouse_sens)
        camera.rotation.x = clamp(camera.rotation.x, -PI/2, PI/2)
        
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("shoot") \
        and anim_player.current_animation != "shoot":
        play_shoot_effects()
        


func _physics_process(delta):
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta

    # Handle jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "forward", "back")
    var direction = (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)

    if anim_player.current_animation == "shoot":
        pass
    elif input_dir != Vector2.ZERO and is_on_floor():
        anim_player.play("idle")
    else:
        anim_player.play("move")

    move_and_slide()
func play_shoot_effects():
    anim_player.stop()
    anim_player.play("shoot")
    muzzle_flash.restart()
    muzzle_flash.emitting = true
```

btw: it is gdscript

so if anyone can help please ansver or if you guys need more info please type it here

Karl

Comment: It is pretty unclear what the problem is, what do you mean by: _flying very fast_ ?  Please read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which explains that you mist make your problem clear.

Comment: the player is flying up REALLY fast like the gravity was minus 2000

Answer (score 0):

In Godot, when working with 2D, down is positive and up is negative. Because of this, you need to reverse your gravity logic in order to apply the force downward, rather than upward.

This would look like:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
# Add the gravity.
if not is_on_floor():
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
```

This also means that you need to make sure that when you are applying your JUMP_VELOCITY, it is negative. You can do this either by making sure the JUMP_VELOCITY you assign is negative, or what I like to do is keep the JUMP_VELOCITY positive and then negate the jump force when applying it, such as:

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
    velocity.y = -JUMP_VELOCITY
```